# Datagridview focus a cell after tab key press

Tags: c#, datagridview, cells

When I'm editing a cell, I would like to press the tab key to start editing the next cell and save the changes from previous one.
How I do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. please read [ask]. Hint: edit your question to show your failed attempts at solving the problem, use proper tags (is this asp.net? wpf? winforms?) as they provide relevant information to solve the problem.

Comment: What you want is the default behaviour.  You must have created a problem somewhere. you need to search your code; we can't..

Comment: This is the usual behaviour of a DataGridView, when you press tab the next cell is selected.

Answer (score 0):

Use the TabStop property of Datagidview, it should do the trick.

Comment: TabStop is only meant to allow access to the Control via Tab-key.